# How Is it possible in Ubuntu 16 to configure a proxy server without terminal.And if possible,how?

Tags: 14.04, networking, 16.04

Is it possible in Ubuntu 16 to configure a proxy server without terminal.And if possible,how?

Comment: It is not clear if you want to use a proxy server (the proxy is on another system) or if you want your Ubuntu system to become a proxy server. Please clarify.

Answer (score 1):

It is not clear if you want to use a proxy server (the proxy is on another system). Or if you want your Ubuntu system to become a proxy server.

For the first case. Configure your ubuntu system to use a proxy server without command line:

```
Settings > Network > Proxy
```

you have a form to configure, either manual or automatic.